# Directive within another directive - scope var undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, smart-table

I'm trying to generate a smart-table directive from within a custom directive I've defined:

```
<div ng-controller="myContrtoller">
  <containing-directive></containing-directive>
</div>
```

The directive definition:

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('containingDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<table st-table="collection" st-pipe="scopeFun"></table>', 
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.scopeFun = function () {
                // solve the misteries of life
            }
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see my directive tries to replace the element by the template generated by the `st-table` directive, using the `st-pipe` directive depending on the first, briefly:

```
ng.module('smart-table')
  .controller('stTableController' function () {
      // body...
  })
  .directive('stTable', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      controller: 'stTableController',
      link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        // body
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('stPipe', function (config, $timeout) {
    return {
      require: 'stTable',
      scope: {
        stPipe: '='
      },
      link: {

        pre: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
          var pipePromise = null;
          if (ng.isFunction(scope.stPipe)) { // THIS IS ALWAYS UNDEFINED
            // DO THINGS
          }
        },

        post: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
          ctrl.pipe();
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

**Problem:**
The `st-pipe` directive checks the scope var `stPipe` if it is defined or not by: `if (ng.isFunction(scope.stPipe))`. This turns out to be ALWAYS undefined. By inspecting I found two things:

1. From the `stPipe` directive, the value supposed to be `scope.stPipe` that is my `scopeFun` defined within my `containingDirective` is `undefined` on the `scope` object BUT **defined** within the `scope.$parent` object.
2. If I define my `$scope.scopeFun` within the `myContrtoller` I don't have any problem, everything works.

**Solution:**
I did find a solutions but I don't know what really is going on:

1. Set `replace: false` in the `containingDirective`
2. Define the `scope.scopeFun` in the **pre-link** function of `containingDirective`

**Questions:**

1. Why is the `scopeFun` available in the `stPipe` directive `scope` object if defined in the controller and why it is available in the `scope.$parent` if defined in the `containingDirective`?
2. What is really going on with my solution, and is it possible to find a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile): "The replacement process migrates all of the attributes / classes from the old element to the new one" so what was happening was this:

```
<containing-directive whatever-attribute=whatever></containing-directive>
```

was being replaced with

```
<table st-table="collection" st-pipe="scopeFun" whatever-attribute=whatever></table>
```

and somehow st-table did not enjoy the extra attributes (even with no attributes at all..).
By wrapping the `containingDirective` directive template within another div fixed the problem (I can now use `replace:true`):

```
<div><table st-table="collection" st-pipe="scopeFun"></table></div>
```

If someone has a more structured answer would be really appreciated